# How to set arbitrary size array in ctypes?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

So I have a function imported from a .dll library that takes in a pointer to a struct of the form:

```
struct D {
    DWORD A;
    BYTE * B;
};
```

The idea of function is that if A is NULL, then function(D*) will update A with the size of the required buffer. Hence, if on the other hand B is an array of size A, then function(D*) will return the filled array with the A bytes.

In trying to import the C function with ctypes, I mimic the code:

```
class D(Structure):
     _fields_ = [("A",DWORD),("B",POINTER(BYTE))]

#function is imported from .dll
function.argtypes = [POINTER(D)]
function.restype  = BOOL
```

But when I attempt in python to run the function twice, I get a type error that LP_c_byte_p_250 doesn't work with LP_c_byte (sorry, I am on mobile and may not have the names quite right).

```
data   = D()
function(pointer(data))
size   = data.A #returns 250
buf    = ARRAY(BYTE,size)
data.B = pointer(buf)
function(pointer(data))
```

How do I set struct up so that ctypes doesn't prevent any sized array from occupying variable B?

Just to point out, if I skip the first function call and redefine my struct and argtypes explicitly, then I do get it to work.

```
class D(Structure):
     _fields_ = [("A",DWORD),("B",POINTER(ARRAY(BYTE,250)))]

#function is imported from .dll
function.argtypes = [POINTER(D)]
function.restype  = BOOL

data   = D()
data.A = 250
function(pointer(data)) #returns 250 bytes to B
```

So clearly I can recreate my struct and reimport my function every time I have a different size, but that doesn't seem right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this struct a VLA? And have you tried `[("A",DWORD),("B",*BYTE)]` ?

Comment: Your description of the behavior of the function is very confusing.  Member `A` of the structure has numeric type, so it can have value 0, but it cannot be null.  Member `B` is a pointer, therefore *never* an array.  And if `B` happens to point to an array element, you cannot tell from the pointer itself how large that array is.

Comment: @John Bollinger Isn't NULL the same as 0x0000 assuming DWORD is two bytes? In any case, yes you are right B is pointer, but that isn't really relevant to the question. The idea is that B doesn't matter during the first call and is basically ignored. We then create a BYTE array for B to point to and the function fills the BYTE array. This is a fairly standard setup for windows DLL files, first call retrieves the size, second call retrieves the data. For some reason ctypes doesn't let me use a BYTE array for B, after I have defined B to be a POINTER(BYTE) and I don't know why.

Comment: @Antonin GAVREL is that proper python code? I didn't know the unpack notation did something to the python BYTE class like that.

Comment: Just a random thought, don't take it seriously ;)

Comment: @BobbyOcean, no, `NULL` is a pointer, not a number.  If you mean zero, say "zero".  And yes, the difference between a pointer and an array *does* matter.  In this case, ignoring the difference appears to have contributed to you making the error that ctypes is directly complaining about: supposing that a pointer to an array of bytes is the same as a pointer to a single byte.  Both are pointers, and they may even point to the same memory location, but they have different types.

Comment: From a datatype perspective, at least, you want to make `B` point to the first byte of the array, not to the whole array.  Ironically, ctypes appears to be pickier about that sort of thing than most C compilers are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the missing ingredient was to use the function cast in ctypes. It seems as though ctypes does some generic casting itself automatically in simple cases, but when presented something more difficult (like a struct built of two other stucts), it doesn't seem to automatically cast.

```
data   = D()
function(pointer(data))
size   = data.A #returns 250
buf    = ARRAY(BYTE,size)
data.B = pointer(buf)
buf    = cast(buf,POINTER(D))
function(pointer(data))
```

This method even appears to work through a c_void_p; in which case you can forcibly use C functions without needing to explicitly define the exact structure they need in ctypes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.  Just make sure the types agree:

test.c (C example to demonstrate)

```c
#include <windows.h>

struct D {
    DWORD A;
    BYTE* B;
};

__declspec(dllexport)
BOOL function(struct D* data)
{
    if(data->A)
        memset(data->B,'x',data->A);  // Return data if size non-zero
    else
        data->A = 10;  // return a size
    return TRUE;
}
```

test.py

```py
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes as w

class D(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("A",w.DWORD),("B",POINTER(w.BYTE))]

    # A pointer doesn't know the size of data it points to, so passing through
    # bytes() and slicing to known size makes a nice display.
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'D(A={self.A}, B={bytes(self.B[:data.A])})'

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.function.argtypes = POINTER(D),
dll.function.restype = w.BOOL

data = D()
print('pre   ',data)
if dll.function(byref(data)):
    data.B = (w.BYTE * data.A)()  # array of w.BYTE instantiated this way
                                  # can be directly assigned to a POINTER(BYTE)
    print('before',data)
    if dll.function(byref(data)):
        print('after ',data)
```

output:

```
pre    D(A=0, B=b'')
before D(A=10, B=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
after  D(A=10, B=b'xxxxxxxxxx')
```

Comment: I have tried for a while now and I cannot get your code to work. I run "gcc -c test.c" and then run "gcc -shared -o test.dll test.o" and then I run CDLL("./test.dll") and it crashes my ipython session, exit code -<large value>.

Comment: @BobbyOcean Works for me, but I'm using Microsoft compiler `cl /LD test.c`. Then run`test.py`.  Just retested it from copying the exact code above in case I had a copy/paste error.  Also, 64-bit compiler, 64-bit Python.

Comment: I am using cygwin64 and have anaconda installed. I am not sure if that is the same as what you are doing. I don't program in C and I am not familiar with "cl /LD test.c".

Comment: @BobbyOcean `cl /LD test.c` just builds `test.dll` just like `gcc`.  Did you use my code *exactly* as entered or try to integrate it into your own code?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into test.c and test.py.

Comment: @BobbyOcean Then it must be a gcc issue